# Popover/tooltip ui bootstrap angular 6 under condition

Tags: angular, popover, ng-bootstrap

I must open popover under some condition. How can I do this?

```
  <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary" *ngFor="let category of categories"
  [ngbPopover]="tipContent"
  popoverClass="change-category-info"
  placement="bottom"
  tooltipClass="change-category-tooltip">{{category}}</div>
```

In this implementation popover is open always after click. I would like to open this popover under condition, eg if 
    `this.isChanged = true`

Answer (score 2):

You can take full manual control over popover by using `triggers="manual"` input.

```
<button ... triggers="manual" #p="ngbPopover" (click)="isChanged && p.open()">
  Popover on right
</button>
```

**[Stackblitz Example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evkzps?file=app/popover-basic.html)**

**[Example with ngFor](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-evkzps-2r5nat?file=app/popover-basic.html)**

See also:

- https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/examples#triggers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `disablePopover` input to prevent the popover from displaying, as mentioned in the [API documentation](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/popover/api).

Assuming `isChanged` is a public property in your component, it would look like this:

```
  <div class="btn btn-outline-secondary" 
       *ngFor="let category of categories"
       [ngbPopover]="tipContent"
       popoverClass="change-category-info"
       placement="bottom"
       tooltipClass="change-category-tooltip"
       [disablePopover]="!isChanged">{{category}}</div>
```